# Magento createBlock method not working, displaying static block data

Tags: magento

Ok so Ive created static blocks in my CMS area, and Im trying to output them inside of a custom homepage template Ive built.

Every document I can find says to output the block as follows

```
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('my-block-identifier')->toHtml() ?>
```

That didnt work for me, so then I tried another way. --

```
       <?php $block = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('my-block-identifier');
        echo $block->toHtml();
```

All the sites referencing this tell me to use the actual blocks identifier to get the block. So then I decide to manually lookup the block_id in my cms_block table and see if using the block_id number in place of the literal my-block-identifier name will work - and it did. So I am confused... Can anyone tell me how I can get the block by the actual identifier, or look up the blocks id by the identifier so that I can grab the block by block name?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the `cms/block` block source, those tutorials have mislead you, or you misinterpreted them.

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Block/Block.php
class Mage_Cms_Block_Block extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
{
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        if (!$this->_beforeToHtml()) {
            return '';
        }
        $html = '';
        if ($blockId = $this->getBlockId()) {
            $block = Mage::getModel('cms/block')
                ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                ->load($blockId);
            if (!$block->getIsActive()) {
                $html = '';
            } else {
                $content = $block->getContent();

                $processor = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_filter');
                $html = $processor->filter($content);
            }
        }
        return $html;
    }
}
```

The block content is always loaded with `->load($blockId);` -- `load` with one parameter always means loding by a database ID.

So, with no supported way of doing this built into the block, you'll need to look up the block ID.

```
$model = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter('identifier','footer_links')
->getFirstItem();

var_dump($model->getBlockId());
```

Answer (score 0):

In the admin, when you are editing the contents of the static block, you will see a field called Identifier second from the top.  Copy the value of that field, and insert it into your code.  So if your Block is called `contact-info` in the admin, then your code will look like:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('contact-info')->toHtml() ?>
```

The value in that Identifier textbox in the admin is also what will be saved into the `cms_block` table, as you're worked out.

HTH,
JD

Comment: Right, thats what I did already as I posted above. The problem is, setBlockId is not working as intended for me, it will only reference the block by the manually looked up block_id field, not the named block in the admin section. I think it has to do with the fact that I am first referencing a Block in the homepage cms page, e.g. {{block type="core/template" template="homepage/home.phtml"}} -  then in that .phtml im calling the sub block. So basically I am looking for a workaround to look up the block_id by the "identifier" (the name)